# The "□□ □□" polyomino

Tags: geometry, tiling

The polyomino '□□ □□' (two blocks of two squares with a gap) does not tile any rectangle, how do I prove/disprove that it tiles the plane?

Comment: For people who don't know the definition:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino

Comment: My first inclination was to try to prove that it doesn't, but I've now managed to fill up quite a bit of graph paper and there's no indication how I'd run into trouble if I go on, so my guess is now that it does.

Comment: My guess too is that it does tile the plane. But I'm curious too look at the proof that it doesn't tile any rectangle.

Comment: @Student73: I think you can do the proof for the rectangle by enumeration, starting in a corner.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can fill the plane, by forming rows repeating horizontally the following figure:
[image]
then attaching the rows with a shift of $1$ square.